# Any way to call contract function without showing in transactions on ethscan/bscscan?

Tags: solidity, transactions, function-selector

I'm trying to figure out how a particular smart contract (or set of contracts) is operating. It seems to be executing a function but the function call never shows up as a transaction on bscscan (yes it is a BSC set of contracts). The only thing I notice is that one of the contracts has a view function that returns a selector for the function that I suspect is being called. Is it the case that if you get a selector to a given contract function you can call that function (through the selector) without it showing as a transaction on ethscan or bscscan? Or is this not possible and I have to look elsewhere for how this function might be called?

Comment: if a contract call another contract then this process it will be shown as an internal transaction in the target contract

Answer (score 1):

If the function is a `view` or `pure` function, it will not show up in ethscan/bscscan as a transaction because a transaction calling `view` or `view` functions directly does not get mined/validated, included in a block, hence, it will not show up.

For transactoins calling a non-`view` and non-`pure` functions (functions that modify the state of the contract), they are broadcasted, mined/validated, and included in a block, hence, they will appear in ethscan/bscscan.

Something to keep in mind is that internal contract function calls will appear in the "Internal Txns" tab: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa69babef1ca67a37ffaf7a485dfff3382056e78c#internaltx

So, you can try to see if the function call you are expecting is there.